# How do I initialize a table view in edit / re-ordering mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I want a table view in my view to always be re-orderable. I cannot figure this out. I have rows in my table view but can't get the re-ordering handles to show up.

For the table view prototype cell, I made sure there was a check in Indentation > "Shows Re-order Controls", but this didn't do anything.

This is how my whole class looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    @IBOutlet var currentTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        currentTable.editing = true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return unitCategories.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(unitCategories[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

    /*func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }*/
}
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement these two methods in order to be able to show the reordering control,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

As stated in the header file,

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

> Allows the reorder accessory view to optionally be shown for a
>   particular row. By default, the reorder control will be shown only if
>   the datasource implements:

```
-tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```